# Can only create a new user when a current user is signed in

Tags: php

So I am creating a forum and currently working on the sign up script. I have the sign up form in the signup.php page and the processing part in the signup_process.php

I have an issue where only a current user is able to sign up a new user when they are signed in, any suggestions on how to fix this. I am not able to sign up a new user when I am not logged in as a current one.

Below is my signup_process.php page:

```
<?php



  include "includes/pagetop.php";
  include "includes/header.php";
 include "includes/nav.php";
  ?>

<?php

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['surname'];
$_SESSION['dob'] = $_POST['dob'];
$_SESSION['emailaddress'] = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
$_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
$_SESSION['sports'] = $_POST['sports'];

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $surname = $_POST['surname'];
   $dob = $_POST['dob'];
   $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
   $city = $_POST['city'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO user
    ( 
    user_username,
     user_firstname, 
     user_surname, 
       user_dob, 
     user_email,
     user_password,
     user_gender, 
     user_city,
     user_active
     )
     VALUES(
     '".$_POST['username']."',
     '".$_POST['firstname']."',
     '".$_POST['surname']."',
     '".$_POST['dob']."',
     '".$_POST['email']."',
     '".$_POST['password']."',
     '".$_POST['gender']."',
     '".$_POST['city']."',
      '1'
     ) ";

     mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());  

     $lastid = mysql_insert_id();

     $sports = $_POST['sports'];

     foreach ($sports as $key => $value){
      $query2 = " INSERT INTO usersport 

    (
    usersport_user_id,
     usersport_sport_id
     )
    VALUES(
     '".$lastid."', 
    '".$value."'
    )";
   mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());     
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Just check to see if they are signed in. If so, don't display the form and don't execute the code that creates new users. It's that simple.

Comment: but new users can't be created unless there is a current one logged in

Comment: @user3617344 What does *that* mean? Isn't the whole point of registration creating an account when you don't have one?

Comment: That is contradictory to "I have an issue when a current user is signed in are they able to create a new user, any suggestions on how to fix this.". So your question makes no sense.

Comment: sorry just changed it

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about inserting duplicate users, you could solve this making on the database a primary key on username and an unique index on emailaddress.

If you are talking about the sign up page being served while a user is currently authenticated, you could create a session variable that is set to true when the current user authenticates into the system. Them you could check if this variable is false to serve the sign up page, or give a error otherwise.

And you have a sql injection vulnerability in your code, you should consider using prepared statements instead of plain text.